# Is there a way to convert a special non-character keys as string type to a key type? (E.g. "Key.f12" to the actual keyboard.Key.f12 value)

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

I'm making a program using pynput that takes a sequence of keys, saves them to a file to later emulate those key presses.

This works fine for character keys ('a', '1', '#', etc.) but not for other keys such as 'esc', 'enter' and function keys (i.e. f1-f12). It just spits out 'Key.' (e.g. 'Key.esc' or 'Key.f12'). It is okay with keys like space, enter and tab for which I can use string representations (" ", "\n" and "\t")

I would like to know if there's a way to convert special keys in a string to the 'pynput.keyboard.Key' type. E.g. Convert "Key.f12" or "f12"  in "hello worldKey.f12" to the value of Key class, Key.f12

I have had a look around but can't find anything on it even in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it in another way,and in official document,there is a function call `parse`.For example,you want to press "Hello world".Save `H-e-l-l-o- -w-o-r-l-d-<Enter>` in your file.

When you read the file next time,use `.split("-")` to split them as a list and use parse to handle them.Here is a minimal example:

```
from pynput import keyboard

# s is the string in the file
s = "H-e-l-l-o- -w-o-r-l-d-<Enter>"

control = keyboard.Controller()
for i in s.split("-"):
    print(i)
    control.press(*keyboard.HotKey.parse(i))
    control.release(*keyboard.HotKey.parse(i))
```

When you run this code,it will type in `Hello world\n`.